# two rules produce the same result in mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a test on my home computer using 127.0.0.1 as the IP address. I made some rewrite rules with a ruleset as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^x\/x$ /letterx [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^y/y$ /lettery [NC,L]
```

When I go in my browser and enter 127.0.0.1/x/x, I get redirected to 127.0.0.1/letterx.
When I enter 127.0.0.1/y/y, I get redirected to 127.0.0.1/lettery.

Looking online at various sources of regular expressions, no article claims that / is a character that needs escaping, but http://regex101.com/ claims it does.

Why in this set of code do both urls I try redirect successfully? Shouldn't one throw a failure? Is there a bug in mod_rewrite I'm not aware of? You would think based on many websites that the second line of code above should fail and the third line should work, but I'm puzzled.

Comment: @Prix you are right about PCRE, but `/` is a not a character of special meaning and does not need to be escaped. The only time it needs to be escaped is if the regex delimiters are set to `/` ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591452/do-you-have-to-escape-a-forward-slash-when-using-mod-rewrite

Comment: @hwnd yes, it does not need to be escaped because of whatever method mod_rewrite uses by either changing the default modifier or pre-escaping the `/` for security or whatever reason. ***However the way you worded your answer was not right and gave a wrong feel of what the `/` was/stand for in regards the PCRE.***

Comment: Is there a configuration file to use to change those regex delimiters?

Comment: @Mike not that I am aware of but you can safely assume that `/` does not require escaping in `mod_rewrite` nor `.htaccess` in most if not all cases where its used along with `mod_rewrite` or `.htaccess`.

Comment: what are the cases where / must be delimited? I'm using advanced rewriting rules

Comment: @Mike I've answered countless questions about mod_rewrite and I haven't came across any that I had to do that for as of yet but perhaps some other member had and will enlighten you on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like by default, the regex101 site uses PCRE style regular expressions, which is used by php, and are **delimited by two `/` characters**. Example:

```
/thisismyregex/
```

`thisismyregex` is the regular expression surrounded by `/` delimiters, and if I want to specify regex flags, I add them after the last `/`:

```
/thisiscaseinsensitive/i
```

Because PCRE style regex uses `/` as delimiters, *if you want to match a `/` inside your regex, **you need to escape it**:*

```
/this\/is\/my\/regex/i
```

which will case insensitive match: `this/is/my/regex`

However, mod_rewrite **does not use PCRE style regex delimiters**, so you don't need to bother escaping the `/`'s. Example on the regex101 site, switch the regex style to something else, either javascript or python, and you'll notice that you suddenly don't need to escape the `/`'s anymore.

> Is there a configuration file to use to change those regex delimiters?

No. But you can look at the [apache documentation for regex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex).